# How to solve this equation for x?

Tags: differential-equations, integration

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{1}|log_2(1+t)-(t+x)|\,dt=0$$
Is this solvable at all?

Comment: Do you mean whether it has a solution, or how to find the solution?  In terms of whether it has a solution, experimentation suggests a minimum for the integral near $x = 0.065$, where the derivative is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points where $\log_2(1+t)-(t+x)$ changes sign can be expressed in terms of the Lambert W function, and then the integral can be evaluated explicitly
and differentiated.  According to Maple, you want to solve
$$  \left( -2\,{\rm W}_{-1} \left(-{2}^{x-1}\ln  \left( 2 \right) \right)-2
 \right) {\rm W} \left(-{2}^{x-1}\ln  \left( 2 \right) \right)+
 \left( 2\,x\ln  \left( 2 \right) -\ln  \left( 2 \right) -2\,\ln 
 \left( -{\rm W}_{-1} \left(-{2}^{x-1}\ln  \left( 2 \right) \right)
 \right) +2\,\ln  \left( \ln  \left( 2 \right)  \right) +2 \right) 
{\rm W}_{-1} \left(-{2}^{x-1}\ln  \left( 2 \right) \right)+\ln  \left( 2
 \right) =0
$$
There is unlikely to be a "closed-form" solution, but numerically a solution
is approximately $x = 0.06444652198$.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with Lambert's W! Thank you.